# Align bootstrap row with label next to it

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to put a dash '-' between two text boxes in a single bootstrap row. I currently have it without a dash, and when I put it in it appends the '-' above the text box rather than next to it.

My code looks like the following (it's using angular 2 with prime-ng library):

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
        <p-dropdown [options]="fieldsForDropdown" [(ngModel)]="selectedField" (onChange)="onFieldChanged($event)"></p-dropdown> 
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
        <input pInputText class="form-control" type='date' [(ngModel)]="fromVal" (change)="addFROMFilter($event)" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-3 col-sm-12">
        <input pInputText class="form-control" type='date' [(ngModel)]="toVal" (change)="addTOFilter($event)" /> 
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-3 col-sm-12">
         <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg" (click)="applyDateFilter($event)">Apply</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want it to look like this

[image: Example image]

If possible I would like it to have equal spacing between the four elements as well.

Thanks in advance

Comment: reduce one div size and put - in to the one div with padding-right , padding-left 0 , and - with col-lg-1 size of div

Answer (score 1):

Just try this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<style>
.bdr {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 margin: auto;
 width: 15px;
 height: 2px;
 background-color: #000;
}
 @media only screen and (max-width: 550px) {
.mt_10 {
 margin-top: 5px;
 margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.bdr {
 height: 15px;
 width: 2px;
}
.mb_40 {
 margin-bottom: 40px;
}
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
  <div class=" col-xs-12 col-sm-3 mt_10">
    <p-dropdown [options]="fieldsForDropdown" [(ngModel)]="selectedField" (onChange)="onFieldChanged($event)"></p-dropdown>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-7" style="position:relative; padding:0;">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 mt_10 mb_40">
      <input pInputText class="form-control" type='date' [(ngModel)]="fromVal" (change)="addFROMFilter($event)" />
    </div>
    <div class="bdr"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 mt_10">
      <input pInputText class="form-control" type='date' [(ngModel)]="toVal" (change)="addTOFilter($event)" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 mt_10">
    <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg" (click)="applyDateFilter($event)">Apply</button>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
div{
display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
        <p-dropdown [options]="fieldsForDropdown" [(ngModel)]="selectedField" (onChange)="onFieldChanged($event)"></p-dropdown> 
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
        <input pInputText class="form-control" type='date' [(ngModel)]="fromVal" (change)="addFROMFilter($event)" />
    </div>
  <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
    <b>-</b>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-3 col-sm-12">
        <input pInputText class="form-control" type='date' [(ngModel)]="toVal" (change)="addTOFilter($event)" /> 
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-3 col-sm-12">
         <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg" (click)="applyDateFilter($event)">Apply</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to add a -
and add some css style like

```css
.dash {
float:left;
  width:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <select style="width:100%"><option></option></select>
    </div>  
   
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <input pInputText class="form-control" type='date' [(ngModel)]="fromVal" (change)="addFROMFilter($event)" />
    </div>
      <b class="dash">-</b>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <input pInputText class="form-control" type='date' [(ngModel)]="toVal" (change)="addTOFilter($event)" /> 
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
         <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg" (click)="applyDateFilter($event)">Apply</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should add the bootstrap styling to the snippet, if you do so you will see that the solution does not work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use bootstrap to split up the input fields and add a - in between like so, this would give you much more flexibility:

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
    <p-dropdown [options]="fieldsForDropdown" [(ngModel)]="selectedField" (onChange)="onFieldChanged($event)"></p-dropdown>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
    <div class="col-lg-5 col-xs-5">
      <input pInputText class="form-control" type='date' [(ngModel)]="fromVal" (change)="addFROMFilter($event)" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-1 col-xs-1">
      <strong>-</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-5 col-xs-5">
      <input pInputText class="form-control" type='date' [(ngModel)]="toVal" (change)="addTOFilter($event)" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg" (click)="applyDateFilter($event)">Apply</button>
  </div>
</div>
```